# Read a python script from file using fread

Tags: python, c

If I have a program in C and I want it to take 100 times an "A" as an argument in `argc`, then I would put `./program $(python -c 'print "A" * 100')` in console.

Now if I want the C program to read 100 times an "A" from a file (`file1`, for example), what should I put in for it to read it with `fread`? (I have tried to put the above python command inside `file1`. It does not seem to work.) Also I have tried to use it like `python -c 'print "A" * 100'`. It does not seem to work either. It would be really appreciated if the script could be in Python.

Comment: It's not that clear what your requirements are. For example, do you actually want the `fread` to read the python command and then run it to generate the "A"s? Or do you want the `fread` to read a file that already contains the "A"s? If it is the former then have a look at [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) which can be used to run a command and get its output.

Comment: @kaylum I am sorry if was not very clear. What i want is after the fread command has finished reading what would be in the stack would be the 100  "A" not the string of the command

Comment: But `fread` by itself doesn't care what it reads. If you want 100 "A" to be read then the file needs to contain 100 "A". So still not clear what you want.

Comment: @kayle As i said in my original question, if i put in the console `./program $(python -c 'print "A" * 100')` then the program would have read 100 "A", this would have been put in the stack as input **not** the string of the command. This i want to happen when the `fread` reads the command from the file

Comment: It's not possible. If the file contains the command then that is what `fread` will read. But you can read the command from the file and then run it with `popen` as already described (if that is what you want to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
python -c 'print "A" * 100' > file1 && ./program file1
```

or are you looking for a way to execute the python script from C (http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)?